# how to resolve error in plotting polar plot in scilab

Tags: plot, scilab

operation -: Warning adding a matrix with the empty matrix will give an empty matrix result.
at line     1 of executed string 
at line   176 of function        polarplot ( C:\PROGRA~1\SCILAB~1.2\modules\graphics\macros\polarplot.sci line 189 )
at line     6 of executed file   C:\Users\LAPTOP\polar2.sce

plot2d: Wrong values (Nan or Inf) for input argument: 4 finite values expected

```
clc
close
clf
s=0:.1:2*%pi*4;
h=1./(s+3*s^2+2*s^3)
polarplot(s,h);
```

Comment: What is you version of scilab ?

Comment: It's version 6.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value `h(1)` is infinite, you can avoid it like this (insert a `%nan`):

```
clc
close
clf
s=0:.1:2*%pi*4;
h=1./(s+3*s^2+2*s^3)
h(1)=%nan;
polarplot(s,h);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: The first componemt of h is infinite because the first component of the denonimator is equal to zero. Scilab raises an error because it cannot plot points with infinite coordinates. The best way would be to completely avoid dividing by zero...